# Matlab 'popov' function

Tags: matlab, control-theory, nonlinear-equation

Given a transfer function, e.g.

```matlab
numerator   = [0, 1, 0, -.5]  %  s^2-0.5     =      s^2  +0.5  
denominator = [1, 1, 1, 1]    % (s+1)(s^2+1) = s^3+ s^2+s+1
G1 = tf(numerator, denominator)
```

Is it possible to determine if this system is absolutely stable using the [Popov criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popov_criterion) through the built-in [popov](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robust/ref/uss.popov.html) function in Matlab?